# Azure LogAnalytics query for disabled Traffic Manager Profile

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-traffic-manager, nested-table

I'm looking to query Azure Network/"trafficManagerProfiles events from Log Analytics and more specifically when Traffic Manager Profile is in status Disabled.

I've managed to find a specific event and found that I need to look at "profileStatus" which is nested in  "Prorperties" -> "requestbody" -> "properties" -> "profileStatus".Check image [image: traffic manager query]

`AzureActivity | where ResourceId contains "trafficManagerProfiles" | where Properties contains 'profileStatus'`

I need to fetch events in LA when Traffic manager Profile and more specifically when "profileStatus" is equal to "Disabled"

Answer (score 1):

Found the answers in this post: [Log Analtyics - How to use "inverted commas" within search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539597/log-analtyics-how-to-use-inverted-commas-within-search-query)

`AzureActivity | where ResourceId contains "trafficManagerProfiles" | where Properties contains '\\"profileStatus\\":\\"Disabled\\"'`